# Centering an SVG element Chrome vs Safari

Tags: html, css, svg, cross-browser

I'm trying to center an SVG  element in a parent  element. However, I'm finding discrepancies between Chrome and Safari. The following code centers the text nicely inside the square on Chrome, but not on Safari:

```html
<svg width="200px" height="200px">
  <g transform="translate(70,70)">
    <path d="M -40,-40 l 80,0 l 0,80 l -80,0 l 0,-80 z" style="fill: gray"></path>
    <g>
      <text text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" style="fill: white" transform="scale(2)">
        <tspan>test</tspan>
      </text>
    </g>
  </g>

</svg>
```

Result:

[image: Chrome vs Safari]

I created a jsFiddle with this test case:

https://jsfiddle.net/yq11jot0/

How do I vertically center the text inside the square?

Comment: I'd guess that Safari does not support `dominant-baseline`. Btw even my Firefox has problems when `dominant-baseline` is used as an attribute - works fine though, when used inside the style.

Comment: It's the whitespace before and after the tspan that spoil things for Firefox. I'm not sure what should actually happen, i.e. whether this is spec failing or a Chrome, Firefox or Safari bug.

Comment: Firefox pushes the text towards the bottom.

Comment: I know, that doesn't necessarily mean it's wrong to do so given the presence of the whitespace in your markup.

Answer (score 2):

How about just using dy instead of dominant-baseline?

```html
<svg width="200px" height="200px">
  <g transform="translate(70,70)">
    <path d="M -40,-40 l 80,0 l 0,80 l -80,0 l 0,-80 z" style="fill: gray"></path>
    <g>
      <text text-anchor="middle" dy="0.25em" style="fill: white" transform="scale(2)">
        <tspan>test</tspan>
      </text>
    </g>
  </g>

</svg>
```

Comment: em units are the height of the letter M in the font.

Comment: Yes, but why does it need to be adjusted 25% of the font height?

Comment: Here's the description of `dy` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dy - I guess, that "0.25em" solves your issue is just coincidence/a good guess from your screenshot.
In my case I had to use `dy="50%"`...

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, Safari wants the inner `tspan` have the dominant baseline set to `middle`. So this also works on Safari:

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g transform="translate(50,50)">
    <path class="node" d="M -40,-40 l 80,0 l 0,80 l -80,0 l 0,-80" style="fill: rgb(247, 61, 0);"></path>
    <g>
      <text text-anchor="middle" fill="white"><tspan dominant-baseline="middle">test</tspan></text>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: This worked for me. In my case, I set dominant-baseline and text-anchor to 'central' and 'middle' respectively for both the text element and a tspan element inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all the scaling and translating (can have issues in browsers) ... does this work in Safari?

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M0 0 H200 V200 H0 z" fill="gray" />
    <text x="100" y="100" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" fill="white" font-size="100" >test</text>
</svg>
```

Note the following:

- Not using `px` units
- Text positioned to the center of the square using `x` and `y` attributes.

Comment: Looks ok in Chrome and Firefox ... IE11 is slightly out ... may have to go with mixture of this and Robert's dy trick ... as long as check on all font stack variants

Comment: This also works. But removing scaling and translation is not necessary. Robert's solution works as well and keeps the center of the element at 0,0 (this would set it to the top left corner).

Answer (score 0):

It is fixed in Safari Technology Preview 174 by making 'dominant-baseline' inherited [1].

"*Fixed dominant-baseline CSS property to be inherited*"

[1] https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-technology-preview-release-notes/stp-release-174#SVG